# java Socket exception error Connection reset

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, buffer, bufferedinputstream

I have an issue with the java socket server, I have an IoT device (client) sending msg(HB) every 1 minute to my server through the socket, when receiving a bigger msg it hangs while reading and an **error appears:  Connection reset.**
after this error happened when the client sends a new msg it gives this **error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error**

server code

```
 public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(this.port);

            System.out.println("Starting to listen on port " + this.port);
            log.info("UTC Server Start");

            while (true) {
                Socket panel = server.accept();
                System.out.println("accept client  = " + panel.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                new PanelHandler(panel, this.listener).run();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Socket server error" + ex.getMessage());
            // restart server
            start();
        }
    }
```

panel handler class code

```
public class PanelHandler implements Runnable {

 public PanelHandler(Socket panel) throws IOException {
        this.panel = panel;
        this.in = this.panel.getInputStream();
        this.out = this.panel.getOutputStream();
}

  @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            this.panel.setKeepAlive(true);

            try {
                handshakePanel();
                readMessage();
                writeAck();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PanelHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


    private void readMessage() throws Exception {
        int count;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        count = this.in.read(buffer);

        parse(setReceivedMsg(buffer, count));
    }


    private void writeAck() throws IOException, Exception {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.key);
            byte[] ACK = "ACK\r".getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] arr = {0, 0, 0, 0};
            ACK = ByteBuffer.allocate(ACK.length + arr.length).put(ACK).put(arr).array();

            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(ACK);
  
            this.out.write(cipherText);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("writeAck Error = : " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming `this.in` in your panel class is some kind of InputStream, your `readMessage` method only reads 1024 bytes. So if the message is bigger than that your application wouldn't capture the entirety of it, which probably breaks the rest of your code (and it would also leave the other end in a state where the entire message wasn't delivered).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes, it happens as you said, so should I change the InputStream type ?